# Problem using the SQL Server import/export wizard

Tags: sql-server, excel, wizard, import-from-excel

I'm trying to import data from Excel to my SQL Server database but when I open it, I get this error:

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

I don't know if it has something to do with using the 32 bit or the 64 bit version of the wizard and I have no clue which one to use.

I used the normal method where I went to SSMS, selected the database -> tasks -> import data, then I provided the Excel file path & Excel version but it still throws this error.

Comment: Are you running it through SSMS or the start menu?

Comment: The obvious question is have you installed the driver; the error suggests you have not. Don't forget 32 bit apps can't use the 64 bit driver, and 64 bits can't use the the 32 bit one, so you have to install the appropriate one. SSMS 19 and prior are 32 bit only, but the import wizard is available as a 64 bit app outside of SSMS.

Comment: Try running the Import/Export wizard from the start menu. You probably need to explicitly use the 64 bit version. If that doesn't work, try explicitly calling the 32 bit version. If that doesn't work, you're probably legitimately missing the driver.

Comment: i managed to solve my problems by deleting the driver and downloading it again it somehow worked , thank you all